Deadlock Processes conveyor structure
Please help solve the issue with subprocesses hanging. I want to create a Python 3.7 program (running in Docker Ubuntu) consisting of three processes connected via queues as follows: Process 1 puts data into Queue 1, Process 2 retrieves data from Queue 1 and puts it into Queue 2, and so on. I've written a simplified example of the code, but I suspect the issue lies in both Queue.get() and Queue.put() blocking the same queue, resulting in a deadlock where processes hang. After some time running the script, the video processing process stops showing signs of activity, and its exit_code is None. Or it may be another issue. Help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Consequently, Queue 1 becomes overloaded.
And there is a config Pydantic model which created from congig.yaml file
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2
import time
from module import config

class StreamCapture:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(config.rtsp)
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            self.queue.put(frame)
            time.sleep(0.01)  # Simulate frame rate
        cap.release()

class StreamProcessing:
    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue):
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            frame = self.get()
            if frame is None:
                break
            # Example processing: convert to grayscale
            processed_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, config.colormap)
            self.output_queue.put(processed_frame)

    def get(self):
       '''
       Function to pass some frames, because of this class is much slower then VideoCapture
       '''
        rate = math.exp(0.3827 + 0.0449 * (self.input_queue.qsize()))
        rate = 100 if rate >= 100 else rate
        rate = 0 if rate <= 0 else rate
        pass_frames = int(round(rate / 100 * self.input_queue.qsize(), 0))
        for _ in range(0, pass_frames):
            self.input_queue.get()

class StreamSender:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            frame = self.queue.get()
            if frame is None:
                break
            # Simulate sending frame to a server
            print("Sending frame to server")
            time.sleep(config.sleep_time)  # Simulate network delay

if __name__ == "__main__":
    capture_queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=10)
    processing_queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=10)

    capture = StreamCapture(capture_queue)
    processing = StreamProcessing(capture_queue, processing_queue)
    sender = StreamSender(processing_queue)

    capture_process=mp.Process(target=capture.run, daemon=True)
    processing_process=mp.Process(target=processing.run, daemon=True)
    sender_process=mp.Process(target=sender.run, daemon=True)

    capture_process.start()
    processing_process.start()
    sender_process.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        capture_queue.put(None)
        processing_queue.put(None)
        capture_process.join()
        processing_process.join()
        sender_process.join()

